# Yield a result from a list of Scala Future

Tags: scala, future

I am brand new to Scala `Future`s and I am working on some simple task.

I have the following function that returns a list of Future and all I want to do is to read the result (and block until all the future finished).

```
private def findAll(className: String): List[Future[Vector[ParseObject]]]= {
    def find(query: ParseQuery[ParseObject], from: Int, limit: Int) = {
      query.skip(from)
      query.limit(limit)
      Future(query.find().asScala.toVector)
    }

    val count = ParseQuery.getQuery(className).count()
    val skip = 1000
    val fromAndLimit = for (from <- 0 to count by skip) yield (from, if (from + skip < count) skip else count - from )
    println("fromAndLimit: " + fromAndLimit)

    (for((from, limit) <- fromAndLimit if limit > 0) yield find(ParseQuery.getQuery(className), from, limit)).toList
  }
```

As appears, the function try to read all objects from Parse.com and return all the objects in one big `Vector`.

(code snippet is very appreciated; as right now I am not trying to learn Future, I just want a solution for this case).

Comment: What if one `Future` fails?

Comment: mm, I could check the resulting size against my size, and then if not equal then re-do the whole calculation again. (just a quick idea)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to compose futures to one you could call:

```
val compositeFuture: Future[List[Vector[ParseObject]]] = Future.sequence(findAll(???))
```

If you want to wait for completion, then:

```
val result: List[Vector[ParseObject]] = Await.result(compositeFuture, 1 minute)
```